# Столкнулся с проблемой matching bracket could not be found в sublime text 3

Tags: плагин, sublime-text-3

столкнулся с данной проблемой, подскажите, что делать
я так понимаю, что это что-то с BracketHighlighter

[image: скрин прилагается]

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас ошибка с тегами. Ошибка на скрине закрывает код. Выложите код сюда текстом.

Comment: Это почти не виляет на работу.